# Can't get why I get a likelihood equals to "1" rather than "VERY_UNLIKELY"

Tags: node.js

Here is my nodeJs code (actually a Google functions snippet).

I expect to get the string "VERY_UNLIKELY" but I go "1" instead.
How it comes?

```js
console.log(`==${prefix}Explicit annotation: ${frames.length} frames`);

                var i=0
                for(const frame of frames) {
                    console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i++}:`, JSON.stringify(frame, null, 2))

                    const likelihood = frame["pornographyLikelihood"]
                    if (!likelihood) {
                        console.log(`==${prefix}No pornographyLikelihood`)
                        continue
                    }
                    console.warn(`==${prefix}pornographyLikelihood is "${likelihood}"`)

                    if (likelihood == "VERY_UNLIKELY") continue
                    if (likelihood == "UNLIKELY") continue

                    // Offensive content
                    isSafe = false
                    console.warn(`$=${prefix}Offensive content at frame:`, frame["timeOffset"], "with likelihood:", frame["pornographyLikelihood"])
                    //break
                }
```

And the logs are:

```
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562406Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: found 1 annotationResults
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562420Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: Explicit annotation: 2 frames
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562432Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: frame 0: {
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562445Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   "timeOffset": {
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562457Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     "nanos": 236572000
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562469Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   },
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562484Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   "pornographyLikelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY"
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562497Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: }
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562509Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: frame 1: {
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562522Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   "timeOffset": {
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562536Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     "seconds": "1",
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562549Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     "nanos": 276223000
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562562Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   },
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562574Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   "pornographyLikelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY"
2023-04-01T20:14:30.562586Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: }
2023-04-01T20:14:30.563179Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: pornographyLikelihood is "1"
2023-04-01T20:14:30.563202Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: $=_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b44: Offensive content at frame: Duration {
2023-04-01T20:14:30.563220Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   seconds: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
2023-04-01T20:14:30.563233Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   nanos: 276223000
2023-04-01T20:14:30.563248Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: } with likelihood: 1
```

[UPDATE]

Well I was fooled by the `JSON.stringify` in the log. When login the actual object without the help of the `JSON.stringify`, :

```
    var i=0
    for(const frame of frames) {
        i++
        console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i}:`, frame)
```

...I get this:

```
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679159Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b51: Explicit annotation frames: 2 frames [
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679183Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   ExplicitContentFrame {
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679196Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     timeOffset: Duration { nanos: 236572000 },
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679208Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     pornographyLikelihood: 1
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679221Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   },
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679233Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   ExplicitContentFrame {
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679247Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     timeOffset: Duration { seconds: [Long], nanos: 276223000 },
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679258Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:     pornographyLikelihood: 1
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679268Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   }
2023-04-01T21:46:22.679278Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ]
```

So, I modified my code to read the likelihood like that:

```js
                    console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i}:`, frame)
                    const json = JSON.stringify(frame)//, null, 2)
                    const o = JSON.parse(json)
                    console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i}: stringify gave`, json)
                    console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i}: parse gave`, o)
                    console.log(`==${prefix}frame ${i}: o[pornographyLikelihood]=`,o["pornographyLikelihood"])

                    const timeOffset = o["timeOffset"]
                    const pornographyLikelihood = o["pornographyLikelihood"]
```

This gives the right result for `pornographyLikelihood`:

```
2023-04-01T21:46:22.680906Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b51: frame 2: stringify gave {"timeOffset":{"seconds":"1","nanos":276223000},"pornographyLikelihood":"VERY_UNLIKELY"}
2023-04-01T21:46:22.681088Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b51: frame 2: parse gave {
2023-04-01T21:46:22.681102Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   timeOffset: { seconds: '1', nanos: 276223000 },
2023-04-01T21:46:22.681114Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch:   pornographyLikelihood: 'VERY_UNLIKELY'
2023-04-01T21:46:22.681125Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: }
2023-04-01T21:46:22.681137Z ? classifiedAdSafeSearch: ==_safeSearchAnalyzeVideo b51: frame 2: o[pornographyLikelihood]= VERY_UNLIKELY
```

I am puzzled. What should I do?

Comment: can you console value of i in every console. My strong guess is these logs are mixed & at the time multiple services are writing the logs

Comment: I just added more in an update

Comment: so issue resolved ? After an update, there is no query!